# FMDB unit test if created table successfully didn't pass

Tags: swift, fmdb

I want to unit test if a table has been created successfully by **FMDB**.

```
db.createGoodTable("good")
XCTAssertTrue(db.tableExists("good")!)
```

I can't pass the test. The error is:

```
 The FMDatabase <FMDatabase: 0x6080000bfb00> is not open.
```

So i try to open it before check exist:

```
db.createGoodTable()
db.open()
XCTAssertTrue(db.tableExists("good")!)
```

Still the same error.

**PS**: `getDatabase` passed unit test without any issue to get a db.

```
func createGoodTable() {
        let sql = "create table if not exists good(name text)"
        guard let db = self.getDatabase("databaseName"), db.open() else {
            return false
        }
        do {
            try db.executeUpdate(sql, values: nil)
        } catch let er as NSError {
            print(er)
        }
        return db.close()
}
```

**EDIT**

```
func getDatabase(_ dbName: String) -> FMDatabase? {
    let dbPath = databasePath + "/" + dbName
    guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dbPath) else {
        return nil
    }
    return FMDatabase(path: dbPath)
}
```

Comment: @Rob You are correct! My mistake! I called ```FMDatabase``` twice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `db` reference in `createGoodTable` is setting a local `db` variable to a new `FMDatabase` instance, which is discarded when `createGoodTable` returns. The `db` reference in your test was never opened. Assuming you already created a `FMDatabase` instance, just open it, not creating a new instance and not creating a local variable:

```
func createGoodTable() -> Bool {
    let sql = "create table if not exists good(name text)"

    guard open() else {
        return false
    }

    do {
        try executeUpdate(sql, values: nil)
    } catch let er as NSError {
        print(er)
        close()
        return false
    }

    return close()
}
```

I'm inferring from your code snippets that `createGoodTable` was implemented in some `FMDatabase` extension or subclass. If not, show us more about how you defined and instantiated `db`. But the basic idea is that you want to make sure you don't create a second, local `FMDatabase` instance and then try to reference it elsewhere.